# Not callable pylint error but no problems at runtime

Tags: python, pylint, callable

I'm trying to debug a pylint error in an existing codebase. Here's a minimal reproducible example of the issue I'm seeing:

```
from cytoolz import curry

@curry
def get_generator(val):
    if val == 0:
        return
    
    for i in range(val):
        yield i

gen = get_generator()

for k in gen(2):
    print(k)
```

If you run pylint on this (I used `python3.7 -m pylint test.py`), you get the error

```
test.py:13:9: E1102: gen is not callable (not-callable)
```

Why is it marked as not callable, despite this snippet executing without error at runtime?

Another question I have is if you change `gen(2)` to `gen(0)`, it still executes, but I'm a bit confused what happens in this case. It returns nothing, so is it still a callable?

Comment: This should raise `TypeError: get_generator() missing 1 required positional argument: 'val'`. Also what is `cytoolz`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo Looks like its https://github.com/pytoolz/cytoolz. It doesn't raise that error because of `curry` decorator?

Comment: I really don't know as I'm unfamiliar with it. If it does, it seems like a very unintuitive decorator behavior (in my opinion... although even pylint seems to be confused about it...)